# Is the temperature of all the molecules in a sample of gas the same?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I would expect the answer to be no, since according to Boltzmann Distribution, there is a probability distribution for the possible states that can be occupied by a gas. As kinetic energy is related to the temperature of the gas, it should be the average of kinetic energies that gives the temperature of the system.

Would this change if the gas was an ideal gas?

Comment: The temperature is a macroscopic quantity and thus is a single value for the entire gas.    Each individual molecule however has a different kinetic energy.

Comment: Is it meaningless, from a macroscopic perspective to talk about the temperature of a single molecule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temperature is a [Parameter of a Statistical Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter) and, as such, is a property of a statistical population *as a whole*. Namely, it is a parameter of the Boltzmann distribution of energies - in your example, the translational, vibrational and rotational kinetic energies of the gas molecules. So, as you seem to have correctly guessed, it is meaningless to talk about the temperature of a single molecule.

The molecules in a gas at thermodynamic equilibrium at temperature $T$ have different speeds, and also different vibrational and rotational kinetic energies if these latter two are applicable (for example, they are not for a noble, monoatomic gas). This is likely what you are thinking of.